# c# store files content into MemoryStream and read back

Tags: c#, stream, console-application

I'm trying to read all files (expecting xml type only) from specific location. My goal is to store them into  Dictionary<int, MemoryStream> dict. After calling method StreamAll() I would like to call required file StreamReportFiles.dict[10] to receive right version of xml file.

Is that correct approach? And how  convert back StreamReportFiles.dict[10] into string or XmlDocument while its converted into bytes[]?

```
class StreamReportFiles
{
public static Dictionary<int, MemoryStream> dict;

    public static void StreamAll()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"c:\Templates\"));
        FileInfo[] Files = dir.GetFiles("*.xml");
        dict= new Dictionary<int, MemoryStream>();


        if (Files.Length > 0)
        {
            long len;
            MemoryStream ms;

            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in Files)
            {

                using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    ms = new MemoryStream();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];

                    ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                    len = file.Length / 1024;

                    RdlcDictStream.Add(Convert.ToInt32(fileInfo.Name.Substring(0, fileInfo.Name.Length - fileInfo.Extension.Length)), ms);
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"File {fileInfo.Name}  {len} kB size added to MemoryStream");
            }
            
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: Reading undefined amount of files with undefined total size can cause `OutOfMemoryException`. Be careful with this.

Btw, if you want to store the data in the memory, it's better to store it in arrays.

```cs
public static Dictionary<int, byte[]> Data { get; private set; }

public static void LoadAllTemplates()
{
    Data = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Templates"));

    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in dir.GetFiles("*.xml"))
    {
        if (int.TryParse(fileInfo.Name.Remove(fileInfo.Name.Length - fileInfo.Extension.Length), out int key))
        {
            Data[key] = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);
            Console.WriteLine($"File {fileInfo.Name} {fileInfo.Length / 1024} kB size added to Data");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to parse filename {fileInfo.Name}");
    }
}
```

Usage could be

```cs
StreamReportFiles.LoadAllTemplates();
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(StreamReportFiles.Data[10]));
```

Comment: Many thanks mate!!! That's solution which fit to my needs! Why it's better to use array over MemoryStream? Also thank you for heads up, but there is no worries - I'm expecting a small amount of xml files with max size around 1mb. But reading time of each xml file is important - so to avoid disk reads I decided it's better to keep them in memory (probably during 1 month those files might be opened 1 milion times).

Comment: @zawier array is easier to handle and more efficient while you keep the data in memory. To manage `MemoryStream` you need to reset its `Position` to 0 after each reading. On other hand you may convert it `.ToArray()` which makes a copy of the contents (doubles memory consumption for the moment) while array can be used directly in this case. Btw, MS anyway keeps the data in the undelying `byte[]` array, just wraps it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to convert the MemoryStream having xml data in byte[] format to XML string back.

For this you can use System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(StreamReportFiles.dict[0])

Comment: System.Data.Encoding -> can't find a such lib. Unfortunatelly I'm using Framework 4.7.Answearing your question: I'd like to save all xml documents into Memory Stream (to avoid opening them from disc hundred times after- time here is crucial) and having then stored in memory I'd like to make some modifications.. That's short story ;)

Comment: With current solution I get Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to 'byte[]'

Comment: You can write like below:
   byte[] data = new byte[ms.Length];
   ms.Read(data, 0, ms.Length);
   System.Text.Encoding.GetString(data);

Comment: 1)   StreamReportFiles.dict[10].Read(data, 0, StreamReportFiles.dict[10].Length)-> Error CS1503 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'long' to 'int' ; 2) Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.GetString(data)); -> Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Encoding.GetString(byte[])'